# proving that If $G$ has at least $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$ Edges then it's connected

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph $n$ vertices and with at least $$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$$
> Edges. Prove that $G$ is Connected.

I tried with some examples and I noticed the following: If $n=5$, for example, then the number of vertices is at least 7. If you divide the graph into two disconnected components, say one with 3 vertices, for example, and the other with 2, and if you start to connect them with 7 edges you'll eventually arrive at:

[image]

And then you'll be forced to add more edges and to connect the two disconnected components arriving at a contradiction.

So I think that the proof must be something like this:

Assume that $G$ has the following connected components: $G_1,...,G_k$.

Then show that even if $\forall i \in \{1,...,k\}, G_i\simeq K_{|V(G_i)|}$ there are still some edges missing and thus the disconnected components must be connected to each other arriving at a contradiction.

The problem is that I'm not being able to formalize this and make the proof. How can this be done?

Comment: If $G$ has a connected component of $k$ vertices then $G$ is a subgraph of $K_k \cup K_{n-k}$ ... try to maximize $E(K_k) + E(K_{n-k})$ ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectivity of such a graph follows from the inequality
$$
\frac{p(p-1)}{2}+\frac{q(q-1)}{2}<\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1,
$$
where $p+q=n$.